# add object to list with properties at same time

Tags: c#

I have,

```
List<Items> itemDetails = new List<Item>();
itemDetails.Add(new Item { isNew = true, Description = "test description" });
```

Why i can't write above code like

```
List<Items> itemDetails = new List<Item>().Add(new Item { isNew = true, Description = "test description" });
```

It gives error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `Add`, that has a `void` return type... which is why you're getting the error. The overall result of the expression `new List<Item>().Add(...)` is `void`.

However, you can use a [*collection initializer*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
List<Item> itemDetails = new List<Item>
{
    new Item { isNew = true, Description = "test description" },
    new Item { isNew = false, Description = "other description" }
};
```

That's basically telling the compiler to convert each element within the collection initializer into an `Add` call for you.